# regular expressions, modrewrite php apache

Tags: php, apache

is it possible to mask this:

www.site.com/latest_news/10518271191304876236

to this

www.site.com/latest_news/

but i still need access in PHP to '10518271191304876236' this part as its used as an ID.

many thanks

Comment: So you want the short url with just `/latest_news/` and the ID to come out of nowhere? (Also: the question title is not for tagging.)

Comment: First example: http://tinyurl.com/3v8z2pf

Comment: You can't change the user's address bar like that without doing a redirect, and the redirect would destroy the numeric value. The new hit would come in with just `/latest_news` without any other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(latest_news/)(.+)/?$ /$1?ID=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

With this `10518271191304876236` will be passed as query parameter `ID` to your index.php file inside `/latest_news/`.

Comment: could you explain a little deeper how this works so i understand please?

Comment: `(` and `)` are used for grouping. You can I am using 2 groups. First one `$1` will have `latest_news/` and group 2 `$2` will have `10518271191304876236`. If left hand side matches `^latest_news/1234$` or `^latest_news/1234/$` it will be forwarded to `^latest_news/?ID=1234$`. `NC` is for ignore case comparison and `QSA` is for appending query string. `L` is to mark it the last rule.